# Sagemaker sparkml_model deploy error: The primary container for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping health check sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

using mleap-spark::0.17.0
EMR- 5.24.0
My code snippet:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
import time

timestamp_prefix = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", gmtime())

import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
from sagemaker.sparkml.model import SparkMLModel

sess = sagemaker.Session()
role ="sagemaker-execution-role"# get_execution_role()


sparkml_data = "s3://{}/{}/{}".format(
    "emr-spark-sagemaker", "emr/sparkml-layer/mleap", "model.tar.gz"
)
model_name = "sparkml-layer-" + timestamp_prefix
sparkml_model = SparkMLModel(
    model_data=sparkml_data,
    role=role,
    sagemaker_session=sess,
    name=model_name,
    env={"SAGEMAKER_SPARKML_SCHEMA": schema_json},
)


endpoint_name = "sparkml-layer-ep-ap3"

sparkml_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge", endpoint_name=endpoint_name
)
```

Error:The primary container for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping health check sagemaker
If I check error log in cloudwatch this is what I find.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'provideTransformer' defined in class path resource [com/amazonaws/sagemaker/configuration/BeanConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [ml.combust.mleap.runtime.frame.Transformer]: Factory method 'provideTransformer' threw exception; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: size

Comment: Are you able to load up the model and make inference against it outside of SageMaker?

Comment: Thanks Marc, it got solved. I trained model outside sagemaker, when it was having proper inferencing, deploy over sagemaker. May be it was issue with model itself.